# Convert a string to bytes

Tags: string, powershell, type-conversion

I'm having some difficulties with converting a string variable to bytes.

**Working code:**

```
$fqtm = New-Object -ComObject Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManager
$quota = $fqtm.GetQuota('E:\HOME\folder')
$quota.QuotaLimit = 15GB
$quota.Commit()
```

**Not working code:**

```
$Limit = '15GB'
$fqtm = New-Object -ComObject Fsrm.FsrmQuotaManager
$quota = $fqtm.GetQuota('E:\HOME\folder')
$quota.QuotaLimit = $Limit
$quota.Commit()
```

The problem is that the value `15GB` is used as a string  rather than an `INT64`. So I tried the following without luck:

```
$quota.QuotaLimit = ($Limit -as [Int64])
$quota.QuotaLimit = [Int64]$Limit
```

Is there a way to overcome this conversion issue?

**Where does the `$Limit` variable come from:**

```
# GroupName example: 'WORLD EU Home Drives 5GB'
# GroupName example: 'WORLD EU Home Drives 15GB'
$Users = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase 'OU=EU,OU=world,DC=domain,DC=net' -Filter "Name -like '$GroupName*' " | % {
    $Limit = $_.Name.Split(' ')[-1]
    Get-ADGroupMember $_ -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties HomeDirectory | where {$_.Enabled -and $_.HomeDirectory} | % {
        Write-Verbose "User '$($_.Name)' - Limit '$Limit' - HomeDrive '$($_.HomeDirectory)'"
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            User          = $_.Name
            Limit         = $Limit
            HomeDirectory = $_.HomeDirectory
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you've put your `'15GB'` in quotes, so it means you want a string. Just remove quotes and PS will convert it to the int value:

```
$Limit = 15GB
```

P.S. I've just checked and it produces `Int64` on my PC:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> Get-Host

Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 4.0
InstanceId       : 1d32179c-6b30-4ff8-9b9d-9321fb71cb59
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : ru-RU
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

PS C:\Users\xxx> $Limit = 15GB
PS C:\Users\xxx> $Limit.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name        BaseType
-------- -------- ----        --------
True     True     Int64       System.ValueType

PS C:\Users\xxx> $Limit
16106127360
```

> I've updated the OP to be more clear. So you can see where the data
>   comes from

Ok, I see your problem now. Try this hack:

```
$quota.QuotaLimit = [scriptblock]::Create($Limit).InvokeReturnAsIs()
```

It works for me:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> $Limit = '15GB'
PS C:\Users\xxx> [scriptblock]::Create($Limit).InvokeReturnAsIs()
16106127360
```

> It would be nice, however, if it could've been saved in the proper
>   format in the beginning of the code `$Limit = $_.Name.Split(' ')[-1]`

Try this:

```
$Limit = [scriptblock]::Create(($_.Name.Split(' ')[-1])).InvokeReturnAsIs()
```

Comment: Yes, this is a valid workaround. But I really need to be able to convert it to bytes/INT64. I can't change the source data.

Comment: @DarkLite1 `[int64]$Limit = 15GB` then?

Comment: I really need a way to convert `[String]$Limit = '15GB'` to `16106127360`. Altering the input as you suggested is not an option for me.

Comment: @DarkLite1 So you can change `$quota.QuotaLimit = $Limit` line, but can't  change `$Limit = '15GB'` line? Where it comes from?

Comment: I've updated the OP to be more clear. So you can see where the data comes from.

Comment: Thank you beatcracker, this does the trick :) It would be nice, however, if it could've been saved in the proper format in the beginning of the code `$Limit = $_.Name.Split(' ')[-1]`, so no conversion is needed anymore later on. It just seems a big hassle now, this should be made easier in PowerShell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93692/discussion-between-beatcracker-and-darklite1).